# Reference 2 cells in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a masterlist worksheet made up of data from 20 other worksheets. In the masterlist, I need column A to equal column A on various other worksheets based on the value in column B. For example, Masterlist column A needs to be Yes where B is 3 because LAB column A is Yes where B is 3. Subsequently Master A should be No where B is 4 because LAB A is No where B is 4.

Masterlist Sheet
A -
B - 3
A -
B - 4

LAB Sheet
A - Yes
B - 3
A - No
B - 4

Comment: INDEX/MATCH Lookup formula will work.  What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, INDIRECT but I'm lost so not sure those would achieve what I'm trying to do. I'll try index/match

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what they call a 3D lookup since you know the page and column information?

The one I use is a combo of Vlookup, indirect, and match.

Ex (=VLOOKUP(A3, INDIRECT("'"&J3&"'!$A$2:$BQ$26"), MATCH(A38, INDIRECT("'"&J3&"'!$A$1:$BQ$1"), 0), FALSE)

A3 = Row Title
J3 = Sheet Name
A38 = Column Title

So A3 for me lookups card payments, J3 looks for todays date, and A38 looks for that agent in my sheet. My sheets have all my agents name across row 1 starting on B column. The A column is all payment types Card, Check, etc.